# Why i keep getting NaN value in my tip calculator?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't find out what is going wrong in my code. Thank you.
I have attached the link to code via codepen.

https://codepen.io/tenzin12/pen/rNmmPbv

```
`const confirmBtn = document.querySelector(".confirm");

const tipField = document.querySelector(".p1");
const totalField = document.querySelector(".p2");

const tipPercentage = document.querySelector("#tip").children;
const customTip = document.querySelector(".custom").value;

const inputAmt = document.querySelector("#amount").value;
const totalPerson = document.querySelector(".number_of_people").value;

const calcFunction = (bill, percent, diners) => {
  const percentage = percent / 100;
  const tipPerPerson = (bill * percentage) / diners;

  const finalBillPerPerson = bill / diners;
  const finalWithTip = finalBillPerPerson + tipPerPerson;

  tipField.textContent = tipPerPerson;
  totalField.textContent = finalWithTip;
};

for (let i = 0; i < tipPercentage.length; i++) {
  tipPercentage[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (parseInt(totalPerson) > 0) {
      if (tipPercentage[i].value.toUpperCase() === "CUSTOM") {
        calcFunction(parseFloat(inputAmt), parseInt(customTip), parseInt(totalPerson));
      }
    }
    calcFunction(parseFloat(inputAmt), parseInt(tipPercentage[i].value), parseInt(totalPerson));
  });
}
`
```

Comment: Some of your constants (like inputAmt, totalPerson, etc.), should be variables  calculated inside of click event, because like you have now, this constants have initial value '';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to run calculations on element values, you need to collect those values at the time of calculation. You were collecting them up front - but then when you were calculating the function, it was using those old values. I moved those into your function. Note how I got rid of most of the `parseInt` and `parseFloat` functions in favor of the minimal `+` operator which does the same thing.

Additionally, I simplified the code a little and put in a validation to prevent totals being run on 0 people or 0 amounts. Finally, I changed your `for` loop into an HTMLCollection `forEach` loop. I find it is easier to read and maintain

```
const confirmBtn = document.querySelector(".confirm");
const tipField = document.querySelector(".p1");
const totalField = document.querySelector(".p2");
const tipPercButtons = document.querySelectorAll("#tip input.percentage");

const calcFunction = (bill, percent, diners) => {
    const percentage = percent / 100;
    const tipPerPerson = (bill * percentage) / diners;

    const finalBillPerPerson = bill / diners;
    const finalWithTip = finalBillPerPerson + tipPerPerson;

    tipField.textContent = tipPerPerson;
    totalField.textContent = finalWithTip;
};

tipPercButtons.forEach((el) =>
    el.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        const customTip = +document.querySelector(".custom").value;
        const inputAmt = +document.querySelector("#amount").value;
        const totalPerson = +document.querySelector(".number_of_people").value;
        if (isNaN(totalPerson) || isNaN(inputAmt)) {
            alert("Please designate the number of people and the amount of the bill")
            return;
        }
        if (totalPerson === 0) return;
        let val
        if (e.target.value.toUpperCase() === "CUSTOM") val = customTip;
        else val = parseInt(e.target.value);
        calcFunction(inputAmt, val, totalPerson);
    })
);
```

Updated pen: https://codepen.io/john-tyner/pen/MWmmLMQ?editors=1111

Answer (score 1):

i analysed your code there is some error in fetching the input value in the code.
below is the correct code. Hope this might work
make the following little changes in your code:

```
const inputAmt = document.querySelector("#amount");
const totalPerson = document.querySelector(".number_of_people");
```

and this at the bottom outside the if block

```
calcFunction(
  parseFloat(inputAmt.value),
  parseInt(tipPercentage[i].value),
  parseInt(totalPerson.value)
);
```

overall your calculator is So interesting.

Comment: Does this fix or change anything? without there being reasons why OPs code didn't work along with a reason why this code does work, it's a bit abstract. I have been through the OPs code and made quite a few changes to get it to work and this doesn't look like it does anything.